# How to align font-awesome icons to the center?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying these font-awesome icons to the center of the page but nothing seems to be working. Here is my code

```css
.center {
  text-align:center;
  width:50%;
}

.icon: {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#icons {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<div class="center">
  <!-- Facebook -->
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/faizan.khan.7146" class="icons-lg fb-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>

  <!--   Twitter     -->
  <a  href="https://twitter.com/faizan_khan698" class="icons-lg tw-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>

  <!--Github-->
  <a  href="https://github.com/fkhan698" class="icons-sm git-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-github" style="font-size: 65px;"> </i></a>

  <!--Reddit-->
  <a  href="https://www.reddit.com/user/pakiman698/" class="icons-sm reddit-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-reddit" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: your code isnt complete, are the a tag children of <div class="center"> ?

Comment: Your code seems that is not completed.

Comment: Just get rid off `.center { width: 50%; }`and then you're good to go. Your Icons sit on a quarter of the screen because they are centered in the div, but the div only covers the left half of your viewport. If removing won't work, then set `.center { width: 100% }`

Answer (score 2):

Just add center tag

```
    <center>
    <a href="" class="icons-lg fb-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 65px;"> </i></a>
<!--   Twitter     -->
<a  href="" class="icons-lg tw-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>
        <!--Github-->
<a  href="" class="icons-sm git-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-github" style="font-size: 65px;"> </i></a>
        <!--Reddit-->
<a  href="" class="icons-sm reddit-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-reddit" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>
      <br>
    </center>
```

If anything goes wrong let me know

https://codepen.io/gvsakhil/pen/ZMoVXY I have added codepen, if needed checkit out

Comment: Note that the `<center>` tag is no longer supported in HTML5.

Comment: I too have seen its being obsolete but its working perfectly for me so I am using

Comment: Thats the spirit! Why care about conventions in favor of progress, if you could just use the old crappy stuff they want to get rid off, but they can't get rid off, because people use it anyway because "it works just fine" for their respective browsers.

Comment: I'm sure like a lot of obsolete tags will continue to work but using center isn't really semantic. Structured content shouldn't be "self aware" about its visual styling, not too mention that it will be extremely difficult to make it responsive. For example, if you want to align left on mobile but center on desktop. Obviously you could style the center with media queries, but it becomes even less semantically correct because you are aligning left a center tag....

Answer (score 0):

-> Just add margin: 0 auto; in .center class.

```css
.center {
  text-align:center;
  width:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.icon: {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#icons {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">

<div class="center">
  <!-- Facebook -->
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/faizan.khan.7146" class="icons-lg fb-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>

  <!--   Twitter     -->
  <a  href="https://twitter.com/faizan_khan698" class="icons-lg tw-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>

  <!--Github-->
  <a  href="https://github.com/fkhan698" class="icons-sm git-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-github" style="font-size: 65px;"> </i></a>

  <!--Reddit-->
  <a  href="https://www.reddit.com/user/pakiman698/" class="icons-sm reddit-ic" target="_blank"><i id="icons" class="fa fa-reddit" style="font-size: 65px;"></i></a>
</div>
```